# Remove Flutter HTML widget's default padding

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-html

There is a default padding in `flutter_html` already when trying to parse text.

Below is the difference between using `HTML(data: ...)` and  `Text(...)` widgets.

***Top: HTML Widget, Bottom: Text Widget***
[image: Screenshot Reference]

How can I remove the horizontal padding?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The HTML or body is having a default padding and/or margin.

Try adding

```
"body": Style(margin: Margins.all(0), ...)
```

in the style parameter.

Comment: Could you give code example ?

Comment: @Aristidios Add this param (style) to the Html widget.
`style: {"body": Style(padding: EdgeInsets.zero, margin: EdgeInsets.zero)`

Comment: Legend, this works nicely.

Comment: liberary updated. now try with `margin: Margins.all(0),`

Answer (score 6):

Html has updated, so I update accepted answer:

```
          "body": Style(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            margin: Margins(
              bottom: Margin.zero(),
              left: Margin.zero(),
              top: Margin.zero(),
              right: Margin.zero(),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 5):

The syntax of redeclaring Html defaults changed a bit for the current package version. Now it should be the following:

```
Html(
    style: {
        "body": Style(
            padding: HtmlPaddings.zero,
            margin: Margins.zero)
        },
    data: text,
    onLinkTap: (url, attributes, element) {
        _onLinkTap(url);
    }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The below code has worked for me. The **"body"** tag removes the horizontal padding and the **"p"** tag works for vertical padding.

```
 Html(data: "Your_Data",
           style: {
           "body": Style(padding: HtmlPaddings.zero, margin: Margins.zero),
          "p": Style(padding: HtmlPaddings.zero, margin: Margins.zero),
         },
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Add  inside the style parameter curly brackets.

```
 body : Style(margin: Margins.zero)
```